# Extract every ID element from multiple df in list and then create new df showing each df the ID was a part of in the list in r

Tags: r

On a recurring basis I need to provide a list of specific IDs which are in multiple data-frames. I also need to identify each data frame that the ID is in.  It could be one, it could be all of them.  These multiple data frames are in a list consisting of only these data frames.

Points to consider:

1. These list are already created from previous process, I am married to them
2. Each data frame in the list will be named and that name is what I need as the column names in the desired_result file
3. The dfs within the list are not consistent from list to list or run to run which is what creates my inability to get through this.
4. the goal is to show which IDs are in multiple data frames and which specific one(s) as in the "desired_results"
5. I AM NOT married to the results format.  Anything that conveys the message will work.

```
#creates list
name <- c("Bill","Fred","Bob","John","Tom","Larry")
ID <- as.character(c(123,345,456,567,678,789))
df <- data.frame(name,ID)
bosses <- df[1:2,]
coworkers <- df[3:6,]
losers <- df[2:4,]
the_list <- list(bosses,coworkers,losers)
newnames <- c("bosses","coworkers","losers")
names(the_list) <- newnames

#creates desired results
a <- c("x","x",NA,NA,NA,NA)
b <- c(NA,NA,"x","x","x","x")
c <- c(NA,"x","x","x",NA,NA)
desired_result <- data.frame(ID,a,b,c)
colnames(desired_result) <- c("ID","bosses","coworkers","losers")

#clean up
remove(bosses)
remove(coworkers)
remove(df)
remove(losers)
remove(a)
remove(b)
remove(c)
remove(ID)
remove(name)
remove(newnames)
```

I did go back and confirm each element in the list is named.  the value is shown as tibble if that matters but I was under impression all table format data is a tibble in list.

Additional code for debug:  Yes I have confirmed case and spelling in my code.

```
bind_rows(passes, .Reference_ID = 'grp') %>% pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Authentication_Status)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can bind them in a single data and use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(the_list, .id = 'grp') %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = name)
```

Comment: Working great in sample data but in real world getting "Error: Argument 6 must have names."   I can't seem to find anything for that error specific to what I am doing here.  In the real world data I typed exactly as you provided except substituted real world column names for "id" and "name"  What am I missing?  I promise I try to figure these thing out on my own but coming under time crunch

Comment: @Bruce Probably because some of the `list` elements are not named?  Can you show an example that shows the error

Comment: bind_rows(passes, .Reference_ID = 'grp') %>%   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = Authentication_Status)  Error: Argument 6 must have names

Comment: @Bruce Can you show a small example in your post that gives the error so that it is easier to debug

Comment: I think I just did as you were requesting ?  In the original post?

Comment: @Bruce Your example is still not giving any error for me

Comment: Sorry I'm being a pain here.  When I run that code in my real world data the only response I get is this error message here, nothing else  "Error:  Argument 6 must have names"

Comment: @Bruce Can you run it on a small subset of your data and check where it is causing the problem.  Then, if you can `dput` that small subset, it is easier to debug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227663/discussion-between-bruce-and-akrun).